# How to do the if or in assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am trying to translate the following code to assembly!

```
int i = 1
int a = 3
int b;

if(i == 1 || a == 3)
   b = 95;
else
   b = 0;
```

I am confused about the part where I have to use or in the if statement. Do you guys have any suggestions?

```
ldr r0, [r13, #0] //i = 1
ldr r1, [r13, #4] //a = 3
mov r2, #1        //put 1 in r2
mov r3, #3        //put 3 in r3
cmp r0, r2        //compare i and 1
orr r1, r3        //or a and 3
bgt else          //if false branch to else
ldr r4 #0         // put 0 in r4
str r4, [r13, #8] //store it at location 208 with r13
b endif           //branch to else if if true
ldr r5 #95        //put 95 on r5
str r5 [r13, #12] //store 95 on location 212 with r13
```

So far I have this!
Honestly looks wrong! So you can roast me I am here to learn so please teach me! :)

Comment: What assembly is that?

Comment: Why are you doing `orr r1, r3`? You need to use `cmp r1, r3`.

Comment: Where are the statement labels `else` and `endif`?

Comment: You typically implement it with separate conditional jumps. First check if `i == 1` and jump to `b = 95` if it is. Then check if `a == 3` and again jump if so. Otherwise set `b = 0` and skip the `b = 95`. Draw a flowchart if you are confused.

Comment: Joshua, I am using asm and emu. asm is a ARM a32 assembler and emu is an ARM a32 emulator.

Comment: Barmar, I thought orr would do "||" in the if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing assembly code by hand will quickly get out of hand and become goto spaghetti and a modern compiler does a better job optimizing, with that said sometimes you want to write a few lines of assembler for some other reason.

I don't think you must load the constants into registers first and the cost of assigning a value to a register is low compared to conditional branching.

My approach here would be

1. Store the value of one of the braces (`95`) in one register.
2. Compare a with 1 and 3 and branch if equal
3. Overwrite the register with `0` if branch was not taken
4. Store the contents of the register in area of variable `b`

```
begin:
        mov r5, #95       // The value 
        ldr r0, [r13, #0] //i = 1
        ldr r1, [r13, #4] //a = 3
        cmp r0, #1        //compare i and 1
        beq else
        cmp r1,#3         // compare a and 3
        beq else          //if false branch to else
        mov r5,#0         // Clear r5
else:
        str r5, [r13, #8] //store it at location 208 with r13
```

*Edit*: I [Found this cheat sheet](https://azeria-labs.com/assembly-basics-cheatsheet/) It looks like there are conditional variants of the `mov` instruction. Then the code could be written like this: Without any jumps at all.

```
begin:
        mov r5, #95       // The value
        mov r6,#0         // Clear r6
        ldr r0, [r13, #0] // i = 1
        ldr r1, [r13, #4] // a = 3
        cmp r0, #1        // compare i and 1
        moveq r5,r6       // conditional move
        cmp r1,#3         // compare a and 3
        moveq r5,r6
        str r5, [r13, #8] // store it at location 208 with r13
```

Comment: 32-bit ARM can predicated *any* instruction (except NEON SIMD), including mov-immediate (unlike x86 `cmov`).  Also, never use `eor same,same` to zero an ARM register, unless you're intentionally trying to preserve a dependency (like `memory_order_consume`).  Unlike x86, `mov r6, #0` is the same size and just as fast, and memory dependency-ordering rules mean an ARM microarchitecture is *not allowed* to treat `eor same,same` as a dependency-breaking zeroing idiom [like x86 does](//stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)

Comment: A fun trick is that ARM can predicate a `cmp` instruction, so you can combine two conditions with `cmp r0, #1` / `cmpne r1, #3` / `moveq r5, #0`.  The `cmpne` only updates flags if the first one found them unequal, i.e. short-circuit eval of `i==1 || cmpne`.  Same trick as using x86 AVX512 masked compare into mask to combine 2 conditions.  (Compilers know this trick and will do it for you; that's where I learned it.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, TIL, I changed the xor. These are the reasons why we never write assembler nowadays.

Comment: The opening statement is silly, compilers do not produce better code, they produce okay code.  And only folks that can hand code assembly well know this.  Everyone else thinks compilers do better than humans.  As a result of fewer and fewer folks that can read and write assembly, the compilers get worse (as demonstrated by modern compilers).  The last thing folks that want to see compilers do well is discourage hand written assembly language.  Compilers can produce pretty good code much faster and more reliably than a human, yes, but you can often find improvements in the output.

Comment: Why use a cheat sheet when the arm documentation clearly shows conditional execution?

Comment: @old_timer:  The documentation is always too long to read ;-)  and even you must admit that even though you write better assembler code than the compiler, the average programmer, will get a better binary by using the optimizing compiler that he will be able to write in assembler himself.

Comment: The arm docs are well laid out esp with respect to the instruction set, very fast and easy to follow.  The armv5 doc is thinner and doesnt have all the extra stuff of the armv7-a, and a new user of the instruction set can easily get introduced.  You cant write assembly without a document.  Certainly the average programmer is not going to remain as consistent or as good as a compiler in general.  But without low level folks we can no longer develop new processors or boot new products nor maintain compilers producing working code much less good code.  as old timers retire or die.

Comment: Need to encourage and support as many of these folks as have even the slightest interest.  We all had to start somewhere and make many mistakes...Some small percentage of those will keep the machines running in the future that we rely on...

Answer (score 4):

I don't recognize the assembly language. But the pseudo-code would be:

```
    compare i with 1
    if true, jump to if
    compare a with 3
    if true, jump to if
else:
    store 0 in b
    jump to endif
if:
    store 95 in b
endif:
```

This also implements the short-circuiting of `||`, since `a == 3` is only tested if `i == 1` fails.

Answer (score 1):

If `i` equals `1` then branch to code that assigns `95` to `b`.  Otherwise, if `a` is `3`, branch to that same code.  Otherwise, assign `0` to `b` and branch to just after the other assignment.

Answer (score 1):

I find the comments in another answer interesting and disturbing at the same time.  And more interesting that that answer did not simply ask a compiler.

```
int fun ( int i, int a )
{
    int b;
    if(i == 1 || a == 3)
       b = 95;
    else
       b = 0;
   return b;
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e3510003    cmp r1, #3
   4:   13500001    cmpne   r0, #1
   8:   03a0005f    moveq   r0, #95 ; 0x5f
   c:   13a00000    movne   r0, #0
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

so that means

```
ldr r0, [sp, #0] //i
ldr r1, [sp, #4] //a
cmp r0, #1       //compare i with 1, interested in equal or not
cmpne   r1, #3   //if not equal then test a with 3, interested in equal or not
moveq   r5, #95  //if either of the two were equal set b = 95
movne   r5, #0   //if neither of the two were equal set b = 0
```

which is this machine code

```
   0:   e59d0000    ldr r0, [sp]
   4:   e59d1004    ldr r1, [sp, #4]
   8:   e3500001    cmp r0, #1
   c:   13510003    cmpne   r1, #3
  10:   03a0505f    moveq   r5, #95 ; 0x5f
  14:   13a05000    movne   r5, #0
```

As shown in the ARM documentation, start with the ARM Architectural Reference Manual for ARMv5 to get your feet wet with the basic 32 bit ARM instructions (and base (all thumb variants) thumb instructions).  Notice in that documentation that the first nibble describes the condition code and all instructions can be conditionally executed (to avoid branches for if-then-else type things).

```
   0:   e3a0505f    mov r5, #95 ; 0x5f
   4:   03a0505f    moveq   r5, #95 ; 0x5f
   8:   13a0505f    movne   r5, #95 ; 0x5f

   c:   e3500001    cmp r0, #1
  10:   03500001    cmpeq   r0, #1
  14:   13500001    cmpne   r0, #1
  18:   c3500001    cmpgt   r0, #1
  1c:   b3500001    cmplt   r0, #1
```

See how the first 4 bits change but the other 28 do not? A feature you see in ARM instruction sets specifically and not necessarily in others.  Some others have similar features though.

Not heard of a32 instruction set, so it is not clear which of the handful or more of the arm instruction sets you are using.  The above works on armv4t through armv7-a.  But tell a modern compiler to build for armv7-a it is likely going to build thumb first then arm only if you can force it.  See the ARM Architectural Reference Manual for armv7-ar (it also shows all the way back to armv4t each instruction indicating which architectures are supported).

This is arm code as well that runs on some arm processors:

```
   0:   2903        cmp r1, #3     compare a with 3

   2:   bf18        it  ne         these two
   4:   2801        cmpne   r0, #1     do an if not equal then compare i with 1

   6:   bf0c        ite eq         these three do a
   8:   205f        moveq   r0, #95 ; 0x5f  if either are equal b = 95
   a:   2000        movne   r0, #0          else b = 0

   c:   4770        bx  lr
   e:   bf00        nop
```

(just to show that it matters very much which specific instruction set a question is asking about and for ARM which of the ARM instruction sets)

You are basically wanting to do a

```
if i == 1 set the z flag
else if a == 3 set the z flag
if the z flag is set (from either of the above) b = 95
else b = 0
```

There are many basic ways to do this and Simson's answer is a clean straightforward approach that saves a branch or two.

```
mov r5,#95
ldr r0, [sp, #0] //i
ldr r1, [sp, #4] //a
// if i == 1
cmp r0,#1
bne skip
// or if a == 3
cmp r1,#3
bne skip
// else
mov r5,#0 //neither were equal
skip:
str r5, [r13, #12]
```

I was focused on that answer, but looking at yours did you mean to place the result in two different places based on the result?

```
ldr r4 #0         // put 0 in r4
str r4, [r13, #8] //store it at location 208 with r13

ldr r5 #95        //put 95 on r5
str r5 [r13, #12] //store 95 on location 212 with r13
```

That breaks Simson's answer.  And mine above.

Most folks would start with this, easy to read and follow, brute force straight from the high level code.

```
    ldr r0, [sp, #0] //i
    ldr r1, [sp, #4] //a
    // if i == 1
check_i:
    cmp r0,#1
    bne check_a
    b one_equal //folks will forget to do this one
check_a:    
    // or if a == 3
    cmp r1,#3
    beq one_equal
    bne neither_equal //or just fall through
    // else
neither_equal:
    mov r4,#0
    str r4, [r13, #8]
    b the_end //many folks forget this branch
one_equal:
    mov r5,#95
    str r5, [r13, #12]
the_end:
```

Or something like it which can then be shortened slightly into this, some folks would start with something like this:

```
    ldr r0, [sp, #0] //i
    ldr r1, [sp, #4] //a
    // if i == 1
    cmp r0,#1
    beq one_equal
    // or if a == 3
    cmp r1,#3
    beq one_equal
    // else
neither_equal:
    mov r4,#0
    str r4, [r13, #8]
    b the_end //many folks forget this one
one_equal:
    mov r5,#95
    str r5, [r13, #12]
the_end:
```

Here is where you start to go off the rails

```
cmp r0, r2        //this is a valid starting point
orr r1, r3        //orr is a logical or, not an if this "or" that
                  // so we are confused by what you are doing here
bgt else          //you are wanting to know if it is equal or not, not if greater 
                  // than
```

It does not get any better after that

If you really meant the result in two different places then:

Still get the variables into registers from the stack

```
ldr r0, [sp, #0] //i
ldr r1, [sp, #4] //a
```

This still does an if this is equal or that is equal

```
cmp r0, #1       //is i == 1?
cmpne   r1, #3   //if not then is a == 3?
```

You end up here with z set if either one is equal or z clear if neither are equal

```
moveq r4,#95        //one or the other is equal
streq r4,[r13, #8]  //one or the other is equal

movne r5,#0         //neither are equal
strne r5,[r13, #12] //neither are equal
```

Final result:

```
ldr r0, [sp, #0] //i
ldr r1, [sp, #4] //a
cmp r0, #1       //is i == 1?
cmpne   r1, #3   //if not then is a == 3
moveq r4,#95        //one or the other is equal
streq r4,[r13, #8]  //one or the other is equal
movne r5,#0         //neither are equal
strne r5,[r13, #12] //neither are equal
```

It assembles fine, so the syntax is good

```
   0:   e59d0000    ldr r0, [sp]
   4:   e59d1004    ldr r1, [sp, #4]
   8:   e3500001    cmp r0, #1
   c:   13510003    cmpne   r1, #3
  10:   03a0405f    moveq   r4, #95 ; 0x5f
  14:   058d4008    streq   r4, [sp, #8]
  18:   13a05000    movne   r5, #0
  1c:   158d500c    strne   r5, [sp, #12]
```

I have edited this so many times I hope I did not leave any mistakes...I will get beat up for it if I did I am sure...Before doing any assembly language you need the proper documentation.  In this case you want one of the ARM Architectural Reference Manuals, likely the oldest one which is directly derived from the printed versions before they distributed pdfs.  The armv5 manual.

In general you will see a compiler will do the opposite and jump over

```
if(x==1)
{   
   y = 5;
}

cmp r0,#1
bne skip //C code is equal so branch if not
mov r1,#5
skip:
```

If you had if ((i==1)&&(a==3)) you would also want to look at the opposite, skip over if (i!=1) skip over if (a!=3) having the two paths skip to a common label.

But in the case of an this OR that you kind of want to have two paths land in the same place by branching to a common label and then have it fall through to the else code if neither are true.  By doing the as written comparison if i == 1 branch to label, of a == 3 branch to label.